# How can I add an event post to the existing post table so its queried on the WP backend as a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am setting up a CPT which is an event manager post, alongside ACF custom fields to create a post called conversations. I would like to add the post via a simple form on the front end.

I have created a form which posts the data to the database table for event manager.

```
if(isset($_POST['publish_conversation'])){

    global $wpdb;
    $rand = rand( 1, 999 ); 

    $conversation_data = array(
        'event_name' => $_POST['conversation-title'],
        'event_status' => -1,
        'post_id' => $rand + 1,
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],

        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],

        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
        // 'event_name' => $_POST[''],
    );

    $table_name = 'wpk4_em_events';

    $rowResult = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $conversation_data, $format=NULL);

    if($rowResult == 1){
        echo 'Saved';
    }else{

    }
    // print_r($_POST);

}
```

I would expect the post to be displayed on the backend as one of the event posts, but for some reason, it's not displayed on the WP Backend end as an event post nor on the front end where the data is queried.

Comment: You're assigning a random ID to the `post_id` field. Shouldn't it be the ID of your "event manager" post instead?

Comment: Yes, I did so because event-manager provides both an ID and a ```post_id```. The event ID autoincrements. But still, at that, it didn't pick it up on the backend.

Comment: Well, without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) all we can do is guess. Please update your question and include some more code so we can reproduce the issue and provide suggestions.